# How to port Windows Store 8.1 apps to Windows 10?

Tags: windows-store-apps, windows-10

I have developed few apps in windows store 8.1 and i want to port them to windows 10.

Previously when windows 8.1 has released, In Visual Studio when you open the windows store 8 app code, in the solution we had an option called target to windows store 8.1, then it takes care of everything.

Now how to Port Windows store 8.1 apps to Windows 10 using C# and xaml

Any help or any article on this please?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Did you get any solution? I am also looking for the same.

Answer (score 5):

The best way to do this is to create a new Windows 10 project based on the universal template and then copy all the source files and assets to it. There's a detailed description on MSDN here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn705768.aspx

and here:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn751495.aspx

Comment: Hi Daniel, Thanks alot for your reply

Comment: 1st link says content is removed
2nd link is imo irrelavant (talks about porting to winRT)

Answer (score 2):

0) Install Win10 RTM

OK? =) 
(But, If you just want to bulid the UWP project, Win8.1 is also ok. But you can't use the xaml designer, inspector, etc.... I can't recomend this way)

1) Install VS2015 RTM and Win10SDK RTM.

By default, Win10SDK is NOT installed. You should select the Win10 SDK from installation option dialog.

1.5) Update NuGET 3.1.

You can see the Flag Icon on the top-right corner of VS2015 Window. Click it to install Nuget Update.

2) Migrate your solution and project.

You should modify your .csproj manually with this guide.

[Migrate apps to the Universal Windows Platform (UWP)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/mt148501)

After that, you can build your app with VS2015.

Note - if you got the thousands of compile error, try Installing following nuget package from nuget console.

[Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.NETCore.UniversalWindowsPlatform/)

3) Modifying your app to suit for UWP manner

Following pages helps you.

[Move from Windows Runtime 8 to UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn954974.aspx)

[Porting Windows Runtime 8 XAML and UI to UWP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/dn705769.aspx)

Comment: Hey..Thanks alot for your reply